# Creating an entity relationship diagram to model the NHL (example problem)

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

We're learning about entity-relationship modeling in our database course, and I wanted to get some extra practice translating a given word problem into an ER diagram. I found [this exercise](https://www.csub.edu/~ychoi2/MIS/Assignment/ERD_Practice.pdf) from a university site:

> Suppose you are given the following requirements for a simple database for
>   the National Hockey League (NHL):
>
> - the NHL has many teams,
> - each team has a name, a city, a coach, a captain, and a set of players,
> - each player belongs to only one team,
> - each player has a name, a position (such as left wing or goalie), a skill level, and a set
>     of injury records,
> - a team captain is also a player,
> - a game is played between two teams (referred to as host_team and guest_team) and
>     has a date (such as May 11th, 2017) and a score (such as 4 to 2).
>
> Construct a clean and concise ER diagram for the NHL database using the Chen notation
>   as in your textbook. List your assumptions and clearly indicate the cardinality mappings
>   as well as any role indicators in your ER diagram.

I worked this out on paper and was hoping someone could review my work (I must stress that this is NOT homework—I do not attend that university). Here is my ER diagram:

[image]

Here are my justifications:

- One `Team` has many (but at least 1) `Player`s. Each `Player` belongs to exactly 1 `Team`. (1:m, both mandatory)
- Each `Captain` is-a `Player`, but not every Player is a `Captain` (1:1, mandatory only on the Captain end).
- Each `Team` has exactly one `Captain`, and each `Captain` belongs to exactly one `Team` (1:1, mandatory participation for both).
- A given `Team` can play against another `Team` (1:1).
- A `Player` can have many `InjuryRecord`s, but an `InjuryRecord` can belong to exactly one Player (1:m with mandatory participation for `InjuryRecord`).

**My question consists of four specific concerns:**

1. Was I wrong to use the `name` and `city` combination as the primary key for Team entity, or would `name` have sufficed? I'm not familiar with hockey, but I suspect I should've only used the name.
2. With the given information, is it even possible to uniquely identify a Player? There's nothing stopping a team from having two players with the same name, position, and skill, is there?
3. Was I wrong to model the injury record as a weak entity set? Should it instead be a multi-valued attribute?
4. Should the recursive relationship `plays_against` require mandatory participation for both entities involved? I figured maybe there are teams that simply haven't played against other teams yet.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)  Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: I don't see any mention of ERDs/models/diagrams in there... How would I even show an ERD using text here?

Comment: That diagram communicates among other things that there is an entity class called "Tem" & a relationship called "play against". Or it would if you gave a legend and/or a reference to the ER method & ERD style you are using. (Pardon any errors from typing and/or reading, I couldn't cut & paste & I had to decipher handwriting.) The content of an ERD is conventionally textually expressed via (pseudo-)DDL with comments.

Comment: Hey,was there any error in your ER diagram? I was also trying this question,and came across this link.

Comment: Can we take another attribute,possibly player id to represent the primary key of the player entity?